# How to map a "map" property in case when keys are another collection property members using annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have entity stub as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractEntity{

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String owner;
    private String website;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String faxNumber;
    private List<Category> categories;
    private Map<Category, ServiceType> serviceType;

}
```

As you can see, the goal here is to create a map (`serviceType`) with keys being members of another collection property (here the property is `categories`). In other words, I want to get `ServiceType` for `Category` stored `categories`;
`Category` is another mapped entity;
How can i achieve that goal using annotations?
Using `Hibernate 4.2.1.Final`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a join table between `Company` and `Category`, with an additional column to give the `ServiceType`, then you can achieve this with `@ElementCollection` annotation.  Check out [this blog post](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html) or search the web for more examples.  Basically, you can use `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` on the `categories` collection, then `@ElementCollection` on the map, something like the following.

```
@ElementCollection
// company_id is the column that connects the company table to the join table
@CollectionTable(name = "company_category_servicetypes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", insertable=true, updatable=true))
// service_type is the "extra" information you want on the relation, basically the value in the map
@Column(name = "service_type", insertable=true, updatable=true)
// category_id is the other side of the join table (connecting to the category table)
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable=true, updatable=true)
private Map<Category, ServiceType> serviceType;
```

I recommend if you take this approach that you get rid of the `categories` list entirely.  It can cause problems and confusion if the same relation/join table is mapped multiple times.  If you have some code that ever just wants the categories for a company, ignoring the service type, you can just get the `keySet` from the `serviceType` map instead.

Comment: 2 years later, after getting a lot of experience, I admint this answer is helpfull( consitent logic) but I dont know if it would resolve my problem back then. +1 fort that anwser (after 2 years - shame on me;()) to you